# how to tell outlook not to delete hotmail messages after downloading

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hotmail

how do I tell outlook not to delete hotmail messages after downloading them? I just want outlook to download the messages and do nothing else. so if I delete it in outlook nothing should happen in hotmail (and the other way around too).

Comment: Is this with Outlook Connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix for my own problem. In the account settings I clicked on more options and then in the advanced tab there was an option I checked "leave a copy of the message on the server"

Now outlook is downloading without deleting the messages in hotmail

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible on your last part - for deleting on Hotmail and not deleting in Outlook.

Basically, by default, when you connect to a Hotmail account, unless you manually specify, it will connect via a protocol similar to IMAP - all emails are synchronised, you delete from one place - it gets deleted everywhere... although it is a bit better than standard IMAP accounts.

SMTP / POP is probably what you are after - it will allow you to get all new messages (and you can specify not to delete off of server) then if you delete on Outlook, they will still be on the server - However, if you delete off the server before Outlook has a chance to download - it will not download into outlook.

Settings needed for Hotmail POP/SMTP From [About.com](http://email.about.com/od/windowslivehotmailtips/qt/et_pop_access.htm):

```
* POP (incoming) server: pop3.live.com
* POP port: 995
* POP SSL required: yes
* POP user name: your complete Windows Live Hotmail address (including "@hotmail.com", "@live.com", etc.)
* POP password: your Windows Live Hotmail password

* SMTP (outgoing) server: smtp.live.com
* SMTP port: 25
      o If you run into problems sending mail, try "587" for the SMTP port instead. 
* SMTP SSL required: yes
* SMTP authentication: yes
* SMTP user name: your full Windows Live Hotmail email address
* SMTP password: your Windows Live Hotmail password
```

Comment: It had allready those settings. When I clicked on more options and then in the advanced tab there was an option I checked "leave a copy of the message on the server". Would that fix it? I left "remove after 10 days" unchecked

Comment: ok outlook downloaded the mails without deleting them in hotmail. :D

Comment: Sorry, been away.... This should be independent of hotmail - you can download and delete and it won't make a difference on the server - unless you tick the option to delete off of server.

Answer (score 2):

For Outlook 2010:

1. Click on *Account Settings*
2. In the *Email* tab click on *Change*
3. Click on *More Settings...*
4. Select the *Advanced* tab
5. Under *Delivery*, check *Leave a copy of the messages on the server*